# File storage on Java - does FS block size alignment make sense?

Tags: java, filesystems, nio

I'm developing cross-platform *non-distributed* disk storage protocol on Java. Files will consist of fairly independent, usually small (< 4 KB) "data chunks". Can avoidance of writing chunks across FS block boundary make protocol more robust, because FS block read failures will touch less chunks? Can I assume that in most file systems start of file data is block-aligned?

Suppose I know, that block size on the target partition is 4 KB.

```
SeekableByteChannel ch = Files.newByteChannel(file, CREATE, WRITE);
ch.write(buffer);
long pos = ch.position();
long alignment = 4096;
if (pos % alignment != 0)
    ch.position(((pos / alignment) + 1) * alignment);
ch.write(buffer2); // will buffer2 data be really FS block-aligned?
```

Comment: There are three drawbacks to your approach. First, the fs block size varies depending on which filesystem you use and how it is created. Second, you assume that the smallest memory page is 4kb, which is not true (it is 8kb on x86-64, and this is without going to hugepages). Third, you destroy some fs optimizations which store data along metadata for small sizes. In short: trust the fs.

Comment: @fge 1-2) library will not try to determine block size itself, responsibility is on user 3) chunks are small, but whole files are giant. Do you recommend to give up the idea?

Comment: maybe zfz or btrfs can be used instead they both do hashing on every disk block and protect your data from silent disk errors.

Comment: Are you experiencing a lot of isolated, single block, disk failures?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan no, in fact it is a course, not production project... Once upon a time I experienced such situation on my own dev PC and lost a lot of data. Since that time always think about this possibility in advance.

Comment: "lost a lot of data" is the key here. That is very different from losing a single block, the failure mode you are considering. Some data collected by Google, who have a lot of disk drives, suggests that a disk that moves a single block is likely to experience a more major failure soon. See (https://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/archive/disk_failures.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> Can avoidance of writing chunks across FS block boundary make protocol more robust, because FS block read failures will touch less chunks?

In theory yes, but in practice I doubt that it would make any difference.  For a start, disc errors are pretty rare ... your experience notwithstanding.

And the downside of aligning your "chunks" on 4k boundaries is that you are liable to waste a significant amount of disc space, especially if your files are usually small.  (And ironically, that wastage means that you are using more disc blocks ... which increases your vulnerability to disc errors.)

> Can I assume that in most file systems start of file data is block-aligned?

In most file systems, yes.  In all, no.

---

If disc errors are a concern for you, I'd recommend that you do one or more of the following:

- Use a RAID disc array in a configuration that allows you to recover from the loss of an entire disc.
- Make regular backups, preferably keeping a copy off-site.
- Replace discs before they go out of warranty ... or if there indications that you've got discs from a "bad batch".

Comment: +1 It's worth adding that the space explosion could be up to 4096 *times,* in the worst case (1 byte chunk size). This is not be sneezed at.

Comment: @EJP several chunks in one block are possible, I was thinkng only about block boundaries. Any way, I refused from the idea, it is a palliative, not a thing making storage really robust